# How To highlight the multiselect box selected item on editing

Tags: java, spring, jsp

```
<select name="projecttype"  class="selt-box"  onfocus="window.dropdown_menu_hack(this)">
  <c:forEach items="${lookupdetails}" var="lookupdetails" >
    <c:if test="${not empty lookupdetails.lookupName && lookupdetails.lookupId==16}">                                           <option   value="${lookupdetails.lookupdetailId}">${lookupdetails.lookupName}</option>
    </c:if>
  </c:forEach>   
</select>
```

The above code is of a multiselect box . Please tel me how to make the selected value to get highlighted .. while editing ..
I used `value = ${xx}` from the controller which is the selected value .. it does not work ..pl help

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by _selected value to get highlighted_

Comment: I mean like -- say i have the multiselect box to select the resources working on a project ... say i choose A and B.........
then I edit that project - so in edit page I want A and B to be in selected state ...So that I can know that these are the values I selected... I hope I am clear

Comment: I don't understand your question still, please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be archived by using spring's form:select tag. Have a look at the snippet that can cover your scenario.

```
<form:select path="lookupdetails" multiple="true">
    <form:options items="${lookupdetails}" itemLabel="lookupName" itemValue="lookupId" />
</form:select>
```

Spring will generate html pre selected for the objects in lookupDetails set.

Regards,
Hemanth

Comment: Thanks hemanth  - I have done this form using ordinary form tag - do u have any solution in that case ...
What ever you have done works well since I have used in Sprong <form:form> in some other forms of my application ! ..